# How to create a simple pop3 email server?

Tags: java, email, pop3, mail-server

The server has to handle requests from a pop3 client. I was able to create an smtp email server, which can handle Telnet communication.

For the pop3 server, I have to support a pop3 client (any one). I tried Thunderbird, but I don't know what kind of stream is coming from the Thunderbird and how to properly handle the communication between the server and the pop3 client.

I could use any pop3 client and the server doesn't have to handle encryption. I just need something that is simple and works.

Comment: if homework, please tag as such

Comment: if you were able to create an SMTP server, what are your exact problems with creating the pop3 implementation? Thrunderbird is easy enough as a POP3 client.

Comment: The SMTP server works fine just with Telnet. I tried implementing the POP3 server the same way as the SMTP by using a BufferedReader and reading the input, but it doesn't seem to capture anything.

Comment: could you provide some of your code, so we can see what you might be  doing wrong?

Comment: I'm creating a BufferedReader and readline() into a string, but the read line comes as null.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11469/discussion-between-m4design-and-rparree)